# Livewire tmp/phpLznimY does not exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, image-upload

When i try select an image to upload it will thow this error.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
The file "/tmp/phpLznimY" does not exist
```

It does not matter if i want to preview the image or not. I heave checked the `storage/app/livewire-tmp` directory and the file is getting uploaded in this directory. It will work on local machine but not on production server.

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
"livewire/livewire": "^2.10",
```

I've checked the livewire config and filesystem config file and these look fine.

```
'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => 'local',        // Example: 'local', 's3'              Default: 'default'
        'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
        'directory' => 'livewire-tmp',   // Example: 'tmp'                      Default  'livewire-tmp'
        'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             Default: 'throttle:60,1'
        'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs.
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload gets invalidated.
    ],
```

filesystems

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I've tried both local and public but the same error still keeps showing up.
the upload_max_filesize is 2GB so that should not be a problem.

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="saveCustomer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...........
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="logo">Logo:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input wire:model="logo" type="file" name="logo" class="form-control-file btn btn-primary"/>
    @error('logo') <span class="text-danger mt-1">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    @if($logo)<img src="{{ $logo->temporaryUrl() }}">@endif
  </div>
</div>
............
</form>
```

this is the validation of the logo

```
'logo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:png,png,jpeg,gif|max:10000000',
```

And i'm not uploading it to the server yet. First i wanted to see the preview. But as i said the tmp file is being uploaded to the livewire-tmp folder just fine. When i check the folder i see that it is being uploaded to the folder.

But somehow it seems like it want's to get the file from the tmp folder. And the filename (`"/tmp/phpLznimY"`) does not come close to what it is actually.

Comment: On your .env did you change the APP_URL? Because if you see the defaut value is going to be -> http://localhost, and  in the disk url will be -> http://localhost/storage, did you change that url?

Comment: Yes now i did but i still get the same error

Comment: did you make the storage:link on production server?

Comment: In the past i had the problem that the storage folder was not updating well, when cloning or updating to a server, what you can try is delete the storage folder and creating it again(php artisan storage:link)

Comment: Yes i did the storage link but no success

Comment: Why didn't you post some of your code? (like the html of the form or the controller). Did you try to use the debugger of laravel to check if the file exists? Go to your controller and add `dd($request->file('name_of_your_input_file'))`, then try to upload a file, see what the debugger returns. Another question, does your form have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?